# MD soft-raid to replace fake raid: How to get rid of old metadata?

Tags: software-raid, intel, md, fakeraid

I had a system running with fake RAID (Intel controller, imsm), which had some problems.

Now I'm switching to the regular MD soft-RAID - I created a RAID 1 on `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`. Seems to work fine.

Unfortunately a run of `mdadm --examine /dev/sd[ab]` shows that I still have the Intel metadata sitting on top at `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. The metadata of the soft-RAID is only stored within sda1 / sdb1.

How can I get rid of the Intel data, without breaking anything?